# Generic Memory Allocator

Tags: memory-management, boost, ace

I would like to create a memory manager/allocator which allocates memory with any specified size.
I have tried using Boost and ACE memory allocator but they allocates only specif type of data

In `ACE_cached_allocator` if allocator is `int` type we can only allocate memory for `int`, cant get for `char`.

example:- i can ask any size of memory like int, `char` or any `class/structure`

please suggest any lib for such application

Answer (score 1):

I think you just want [malloc](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/malloc/).  You can allocate memory for an array of 20 `int` like this:

```
int *a = (int *)malloc(sizeof *a * 20);
a[0] = 1234;
a[1] = 4567;
free(a);
```

If you have a structure or class with type `Foo` it's just:

```
Foo *fp = (Foo *)malloc(sizeof *fp);
```

The answer seems simple, so did I misunderstand your question?

(Note: the casts aren't necessary in C.)